# Exporting a writable database to the SD card and importing to Visual Studio

Tags: android, database, visual-studio

I have an app that exports its database to the SD card of my phone. But when I try to import my database using the Visual Studio app, I get an error saying:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll

Additional information: attempt to write a readonly database

attempt to write a readonly database
```

Here is the export database function:

```js
 public void ExportDatabase(View view)
    {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("ClassRecords", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
        
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        FileChannel source= null;
        FileChannel destination = null;

        File currentDB = getDatabasePath("ClassRecords");
        File backupDB = new File (sd, "ClassRecords.db");
        try
        {

            source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source,0, source.size());
            source.close();
            destination.close();


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Export Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            displayExceptionMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

How can I make my database writable/readable by my Visual Studio app?

Comment: Perhaps you should copy the file to your pc and check that its size is nonzero and set it to writable if necessary, to eliminate any oddities of trying to access it over MTP.  Also, I wouldn't consider it guaranteed that a different build of sonething calling itself sqlite will be able to do so.  You could dump the db as a set of commands to recreate it.  In a more sophisticated direction, you could implement a network bridge and access it like a normal remote sql database, sending commands via your app to the android sql engine.

Comment: In short, it's not possible to make it writable in the SD card using code? I tried copying it first to the pc and it worked.

Comment: It's probably possible to make it *locally* writable on the SD card, but (just speculation) perhaps *not* by an off-board program trying to do so over the MTP interface.  Even though you can probably write a new file via MTP, database access may involved more complex filesystem operations.  Sharing a database file between distinct programs is generally not a good idea anyway.

Comment: If sharing a database file between distinct programs is not a good idea, how do developers create programs that have mobile and desktop versions with syncing? (This question is irrelevant to the topic but I'm curious how they make things possible)

Comment: They host the database on a server somewhere and wrap it with an application-specific server which only permits untrusted clients to perform certain approved operations (generally not in raw SQL).  That server interacts with the database engine itself via SQL commands over a network or network-like interface, which is what I was suggesting your might implement.  The actual database file is only opened by the database engine, or perhaps occasionally by offline maintenance tools.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. I'm just a beginner at Android programming and this is the simplest way I can understand syncing databases. I cannot create complex algorithms yet but I thank you for the suggestions and will use it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the database to the PC and import it from there. This is the simplest way according to @Chris Stratton

Comment: Hopefully you are doing this only to gain visibility into state while developing.  Moving a file between distinct database engine builds introduces a compatibility risk, and trying to make a direct connection between a device and a PC is a bit too involved for most end users.